# Unable to read from content://sms/all

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider

I'm developing an app which requires threaded sms.  I was able to retrieve contents from inbox, but in the threaded view sms must be filled with both inbox and sent items.

Separately both `content://sms/inbox` and `content://sms/sent` are working well.

How do I join contents from two URI's and order by time?

Can I use `content://sms/all`?

Null value is returned for cursor when ALL CONTENT URI is used.

How to do this?

Comment: Which version of android are you using? Also which phone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At last found the answer for this..

```
content://sms/all
```

is something which i couldnt find.

But for retrieving both sent and received we can use

```
Uri selectUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");

Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(selectUri,null,"thread_id="+threadid, null,"DATE desc");
```

This snippet fetches and displays in descending order

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. For this,you can use MatrixCursor.What I have done is-

1. Get all sms from `content://sms/inbox` for a thread_id
2. Get all sms from `content://sms/sent` for a thread_id
3. Maintain an arraylist and sort them in the order you want(I did this using bubble sort)
4. Now define and initialize the matrixCursor

   (Refer this: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/470dd3a1703848eb/d7e70618ce413261?q=MatrixCursor+join+two+tables for MatrixCursor )
5. Add all the sorted records to your matrixCursor

   (Please note that adding this record should be in the sequence of at what time and from which folder(inbox or sent) they come.MatrixCursor simply lets you create a custom cursor so you need to maintain the sequence.)

Comment: What does the content://sms/all contain ?

Comment: @siva: i don't have any idea.